# Vue add class on clicked item in loop and remove from other items

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a loop where I loop over an Array.

for each item in this array I render a new component. Now when a user clicks on a certain component I only want to add a class to that component to highlight it and remove it from others that have it. Think of it as a menu active item.

```
<step-icon
  v-for="(step, currentStep) in steps"
/>

data() {
  return {
    steps: [{foo: 'bar'}, {foo2: 'bar2'}]
  }
}
```

my step-icon.vue:

```
<template>
  <div :class="{'selected': selected}" @click="clickStep()">
    hello
  </div>
</template>

data() {
  return {
    selected: false
  }
},
methods: {
  clickStep() {
      this.selected = true;
  }
}
```

This works only 1 way, I can only add the selected class but never remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple example illustrating your use case since you didn't provided enough detail to go with. Below you can find the items selected and unselected. Firstly, we added a key `isSelected` and set it to false as default. This will act as a status for all items.

```
steps: [
  {key:"0", tec:"foo", isSelected:false},
  {key:"1", tec:"bar", isSelected:false},
  {key:"2", tec:"foo2", isSelected:false},
  {key:"3", tec:"bar2", isSelected:false},
]
```

Next, we looped over the array and displayed all the items.

```
  <ul>
    <li 
        v-for="l in steps" 
        id="l.key"
        @click="select(l.key, l.isSelected)"
        v-bind:class="{ selected : l.isSelected, notselected : !l.isSelected }"
        > {{ l.tec }} </li>
   <ul>
```

Here you can se we have set our status property `isSelected` on v-bind directive which will add or remove the class based on the value of `isSelected`.

Next, once the item is clicked we will trigger `select` method.

```
  methods: {
    select(key) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.steps.length; i++) {
        if (this.steps[i].key !== key) {
          this.steps[i].isSelected = false
        }
      }

      this.toggleSelection(key)
    },
    toggleSelection(key) {
      const stepsItem = this.steps.find(item => item.key === key)
      if (stepsItem) {
        stepsItem.isSelected = !stepsItem.isSelected
      }
    }
  }
```

The select method will firstly unselect all those except the one which is selected and then call `toggleSelection` which will set the selected Item to true or false.

**Complete Code:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    steps: [
      {key:"0", tec:"foo", isSelected:false},
      {key:"1", tec:"bar", isSelected:false},
      {key:"2", tec:"foo2", isSelected:false},
      {key:"3", tec:"bar2", isSelected:false},
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    select(key) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.steps.length; i++) {
        if (this.steps[i].key !== key) {
          this.steps[i].isSelected = false
        }
      }

      this.toggleSelection(key)
    },
    toggleSelection(key) {
      const stepsItem = this.steps.find(item => item.key === key)
      if (stepsItem) {
        stepsItem.isSelected = !stepsItem.isSelected
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.selected {
  background: grey;
}
.notselected {
  background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li 
        v-for="l in steps" 
        id="l.key"
        @click="select(l.key, l.isSelected)"
        v-bind:class="{ selected : l.isSelected, notselected : !l.isSelected }"
        > {{ l.tec }} </li>
   <ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this but the 'selected' class stays on the items that I've clicked before.
So for example if I click on item 1 it gets the class selected and then click on item 2 it also gets the same class

Comment: provide complete css

Comment: I don't have any css yet but I can see multiple instances of my step-icon component and they have a selected class when i click on them but it doesn't get removed. For example i click on step-icon 1 it gets the class -> i click on step icon 2 it also gets the class

Answer (score 0):

You can keep all the `step` state in the parent component.

Now the parent component can listen for `toggle_selected` event from the nested one, and call `toggle_selected(step)` with the current step as a param.

`Toggle_selected` method should deselect all steps except the current one, and for the current one just toggle the `selected` prop.

If You would like to modify more props of the step in the nested component You could use `.sync` modifier (`:step.sync="step"`) and then `this.@emit('update:step', newStepState)` in the nested component.

I've also made a snippet (my first). In this example I omitted `clickStep` and just put `@click="$emit('toggle_selected')` in the `step-icon` component.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // for this example only defined component here
  components: {
    'step-icon': {
      props: { step: Object }
    }
  },
  data: {
    steps: [
      { name: 'Alfa', selected: false},
      { name: 'Beta', selected: false},
      { name: 'Gamma', selected: false},
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle_selected(step) {
      this.steps.filter(s => s != step).forEach(s => s.selected = false);
      step.selected = true;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.step-icon {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.step-icon.selected {
  background: #07c;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<!-- Ive used inline-template for this example only -->
<div id="app"> 
  <step-icon v-for="(step, currentStep) in steps" :key="currentStep"
      :step.sync="step" 
      @toggle_selected="toggle_selected(step)" inline-template>
    <div class="step-icon" 
         :class="{selected: step.selected}"
         @click="$emit('toggle_selected')">
      {{ step.name }}
    </div>
  </step-icon>


</div>
```

Comment: what is `:step.sync="step"`?

Comment: Sorry, It's not really needed in this example.
The `.sync` modifier informs the component to except an `update` event from the nested component with the new value for the binded property.

You can read more about `.sync` modifier here (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)